# zend framework - error_reporting - blank page

Tags: zend-framework, error-reporting

zend framework wont show any error report (blank page) if error is in bootstrap

php.ini:

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
display_startup_errors = On
log_errors = On
log_errors_max_len = 0
report_zend_debug = 1
error_log = "/usr/local/zend/var/log/php.log"
```

Bootstrap.php:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL );
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

application.ini: (in htaccess set ENV to development)

```
[development : production]
phpSettings.error_reporting = E_ALL^E_NOTICE
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

and still if i make some error (forget ; ) i get blank page instead of some error report

tested on 
ZendFramework 1.8/1.11
Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
PHP/5.3.5 ZendServer/5.0

Comment: With all these settings and with your correction, I can't still see a single error =/ Any ideas why? =(

Answer (score 1):

you should do it zend framework's way, by setting it in youproj/application/configs/application.ini

```
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
```

Comment: thx, problem was phpSettings.error_reporting = E_ALL^E_NOTICE

Comment: @kuko: if you found the solution, you should post it as a separate answer, and mark your own answer as accepted!